What is the minimum value of the expression?
Given reals $x_i \ge 0$ for $i=1,2,3,...,2n$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{2n}x_i=1$ find the minimum value of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i+\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n}{x_i}^2$.
I tried the case $n=1$ and got the value $\frac{3}{4}$. My guess is that in the answer it must be $x_1=x_2=...=x_n=a$ and $x_{n+1}=x_{n+2}=...=x_{2n}=b$ and hence to reduce the problem to finding the minimum of $a+b^2$ given $a+b= \frac{1}{n}$.
But I cannot make any progress in this direction. Please help by providing detailed and elementary proof. Thanks.
